# Unsupported media type even if not passing any Content-Type in header

Tags: curl, postman, aws-api-gateway, content-type, request-headers

I have created some APIs using AWS API Gateway with Lambda functions.

Under "**Integration Request"** I have selected " When there are no templates defined (recommended) " with Content-Type "application/json". As [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html) says if you do not pass Content-Type in header it is by default "application/json". So I am not passing it and when I dont pass I am getting error "**unsupported media type**" error.

I have tried all possible combination of method request, integration request etc from AWS API gateway but no success.

When I am passing header "application/json for content-type" then I am getting output otherwise error of unsupported.

Please help me guys to solve this or ant valid reason why this is the issue.

**Note :** When I am testing api within the AWS gui and not passing header it is working but when I hit via postman or via CURL using terminal, getting error. This is strange.

Need your expertise, thanks.

Comment: Are you certain no `Content-Type` header is being implicitly added by the other tools? (`curl -v ...`)

Comment: the issue was postman and curl by default sets plain text in header thats why it was giving error.

Comment: @AphroPfotte thank you for sharing, that was my case as well. To fix I had to switch the request body from a key-value form to *Raw* → *JSON*